# Variable don't update from sfml event loop

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using sfml library for my graphics. During paused I want to avoid drawing on the screen. I want to intercept a spacebar press using sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed. In the debug mode, the event is successfully intercepted but failed in normal execution, why? The bool variable 'paused' don't seemed to update.

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                /*..*/              
                if (event.type = Event::KeyPressed) {
                    if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Space) {
                        if (!paused) {
                            paused = true;// UDATE HERE
                        }
                        else
                            if (paused)
                            {
                                paused = false; // UDATE HERE
                            }
                    }
                }
    }    
    if (!paused)  //// UDATE DONT SEEM TO AFFECT HERE
    {
        /* draw here */
    }    
}
```

**Edited**: Even tried by declaring the variable paused as atomic, but still don't work.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. The process of attempting to create such an example might help you discover the problem.

Comment: Also, if something seems to work in a "debug" build but fail in an (optimized) "release" build, it's mostly a sign of you doing something that leads to *undefined behavior*. Build with extra warnings and treat any possible warning as an error that must be fixed. That should be a good start to avoid such problems. If you don't get any warnings then you need to use other debugging methods ([rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or "printf" debugging) together with code-review of your [mcve] to help figure it out. Perhaps you have and use uninitialized variables?

Comment: I will change code to make it minimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Event::KeyReleased` instead of the `Event::KeyPressed` as the key press gets called every loop that a key is down leading to many enters while the Release event is only called once per click.

Comment: That's good practice. But I had declared `using namespace sf;` else the program won't even work.

Comment: ah gotcha, perhaps try using the unicode instead then? I beleive its event.text.unicode == 18 (the 18 might be wrong but if I remember correctly that should be space char)

Comment: In debug mode, the keyboard  event is intercepted and working normally.

Comment: Ok I got it!! use Event::KeyReleased event instead of Event::KeyPressed as  the pressed event goes off as long as there is a key pressed when youre only looking for a single press

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is problem of key rebounce. I fixed it. If you update your reply, I can accept  it as the right answer.

Comment: @ark1974 I you know that it's bad, why did you do it(talking about the `using namespace sf`)?!

Comment: @NikitaDemodov: Developing an app for my son's Youtube -  simplicity and time is the factor here.

Comment: I use a debounce algo to set right the issue though.

Comment: @ark1974 oh that sounds interesting. But why does your son need an app for his YouTube -- just wondering (p.s. good luck to him with growing his channel)

Comment: @NikitaDemodov: Thanks. The app ingest a time_code file and generates all guitar tabs and lyric with millisec accuracy on the fly in HD graphics.